# How to Integrate JMeter with VSTS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jmeter, azure-devops

I am Using JMeter(3.2), I have some API requests/methods in my JMeter which are running and able to fetch output. Now I want to Integrate JMeter with VSTS. whenever there is a build happened in VSTS my jmx file should also get triggered and execute all API Requests/methods and give the report.
Please help me achieve this.

Comment: Here's a tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/get-started-jmeter-test?view=vsts
But it's better to ask specific "something didn't work" questions here

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT  hey starian, i solved this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call JMeter test during vsts build, for example Command Line (e.g. `jmeter -n –t test.jmx -l testresults.jtl`)

[Non-GUI Mode (Command Line mode)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)